# How do I UPDATE from a SELECT of same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I should update a column of table by converting other column of same table in oracle. something like this:

```
update table1 set colum1=(select TO_CHAR(column2) from table1)
```

but I have this error

> single-row subquery returns more than one row

could I do this?

Comment: You are getting this error, because the update updates row by row and for every row it runs the subquery. For this to work, the subquery would have to return only one row. As you want to update a column with a value from the same row however, you can select it right away as shown in Littlefoot's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just

```
update table1 set
  column1 = to_char(column2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ever need it for more dynamic value generation, use `WHERE` to match a specific record

```
update table1 a
set colum1 = (select TO_CHAR(column2) from table1 b where b.id = a.id)
where a.id = .... -- <-- optional, for specific records
```